# i want to be sure that woocomerce doesn't sells over the stock

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, e-commerce, stock, mercadopago

this is my first question and im not a programmer. English isn't my natural Language either.

I need to reduce to 0 or to the minimum possible the chances of woommerce taking orders or accepting payments when the stock reaches 0.

I simulated 2 purchases at the same time and both were received and the stock counter got to -1.

i expect a lot of people buying products at the same time in my website and I want to avoid giving money back because of sells above the stock.

i had another problem with "Mercado Pago" payment method. once an order was already cancelled (due to the time limit) it let the payment be finalised.

thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

I found out that your issue matches this one: https://wordpress.org/support/topic/negative-stock-quantity/

Also, it could be your payment gateway capturing the payments later or something which is causing the order status to be delayed. In such cases, the stock does go to a negative number which is a known issue.